# Modify C# Code BEFORE Compile in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

i've got a similiar Problem like the question here: [Create MSBuild custom task to modify C# code *before* compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153602/create-msbuild-custom-task-to-modify-c-sharp-code-before-compile)

I need to change .cs files before compilation. Of course i don't want them to get changed in place, because of the version control. I already figured out, that a Custom MSBuild Task might be the right choice to do the job.

Quote of the answer from the above question:

Create custom task that accepts the list of cs files to adapt prior to compilation

- The custom task adapts the list of files received and creates them on disk
- The custom task sets the list of changed files on the output parameter
- The output of the task would replace the original cs files list
- The compilation is done against the changed files.

The solution seems clear and fine, but what i can't find out (all for Visual Studio 2012):

- What target should that task get? BeforeCompile or is this too late?
- How exactly can i give the "files for compilation" as parameter into the task? How is it defined?
- How is the output defined exactly so that the compilation uses the modified files?

Thanks, it would be nice if somebody can help me with an example :-)

Comment: wouldn't an easier workflow be to write an msbuild script that takes the files, modifies them, creates a vcproj from template with the new files and then builds it?

Comment: It might be an easy way to just copy the files somewhere as backup and  transform all sourcefiles  in a console pre-build step. Then after the regular build, with a post-build-step, restore the previosly saved source files. But that doesn't feel very elegant ;)

Answer (score 1):

A customer of mine asked me to replace some version and copyright information in some AssemblyInfo.cs files prior to the compile. I'm doing this via FileUpdate task with a RegEx in place. This of course leads to modified files. But that's no problem at all, just use the Exec task and run "svn revert" at the end of the build job:

```
    <Target Name="RevertModifications">
    <Message Text="reverting modifications..." />
    <Exec Command="svn revert -R $(RootDir)"/>
</Target>
```

Perhaps that might help?