# Using a consistent parameter name across methods

Tags: c#

Sometimes, especially when writing a service using WCF... the server and the host need to share the same parameter name in the method call... otherwise when a client sends a value to the server and the parameter name had an accidental uppercase character instead of the lowercase the client has, the value becomes null. This can be very frustrating if working with an enormous service.

My question is, and I feel like it doesn't exist, yet... is it possible to defined a parameter name from an enumerator of some sort? For example:

**Server**

```
void Send(string Turkey)
```

becomes

```
void Send(string Names.Turkey)
```

**Client**

```
void Send(string turkey)
```

becomes

```
void Send(string Names.Turkey)
```

Where Names.Turkey is defined elsewhere as the parameter name to be used across an entire solution?

Cheers.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Can C# be extended to allow this? Is there a definite reason as to why this is not possible?

Comment: You can kind of do this with custom build tasks - run a task to scan your files and replace `YOURTOKEN` with the variable. I'd think hard about this though, it's unorthodox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153602/create-msbuild-custom-task-to-modify-c-sharp-code-before-compile

Comment: Yah, I don't think I would go this route. I take it there isn't another way. Maybe possibly by extending C# via reflection?

Comment: Reflection has nothing to do to your case. You need to change how the compiler works. Reflection works when assembly is already compiled.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, If you add an answer, I'll mark it... if you know of any custom .NET compilers I'd like to look into this more.